# A Better way to check if the new value is logically predecessor to the current value

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have an object that can have a bunch of statuses. A third party also sends an updated status for this object. I need to better way to check if the newly received status is allowed on the target object based on if the current status is logically ahead or not.

For example, a `customer` can have a bunch of statutes `(CREATED, PROCESSED, UPDATED_STAGE1, UPDATED_STAGE2, UPDATED_STAGE3, UPDATED_STAGE4)` etc. These statuses are all chronologically next stages for the customer.

For example, if the customer is in UPDATED_STAGE2 then it can only have new status as `UPDATED_STAGE3` or `UPDATED_STAGE4`. If the third party sends a status `UPDATED_STAGE1` then it is not allowed.

How do I check if the newly received status is chronologically next status only? The status can be any next status. For example, a customer currently in `UPDATED_STAGE2` can receive `UPDATED_STAGE4` directly and that is ok. It can not however receive any status before `UPDATED_STAGE2`.

This can be done with a bunch of if conditions but is there a better way to do it?

```
public void setNewCustomerStatus(newStatus) {
  ... logic here that checks, the newStatus is only logically next to the current status.
}
```

**Edit based on the comments:**

1. These statuses are part of the enum
2. Ideally a state machine will maintain this requirement really nicely but the cost of keeping a state machine outperforms the requirement. So trying to find a way that does not involve a state machine.

Comment: What type are these statuses represented as? Do you have an enum? Or are they just strings? Or named integer constants?

Comment: You’re describing a state machine; there are a ton of ways this can be implemented.

Comment: If the minimum complexity of achieving one thing is N, then no matter what method you use, it will not make its complexity less than N, just make it look more elegant, such as applying some design patterns, which may be better maintained later 
.

Comment: For example, if you want to eat in the morning, your request is that if there is milk, then you must eat bread. If there is a glass of milk on the table, then 1. You need to make a bread 2. Tell your mother that if there is milk, I will eat bread, no matter where 
In this way, you can’t escape making bread, but you just add an object “Mom” and entrust the bread making to “Dear Mom”, so you, as the main body eating breakfast, will save you trouble

Comment: Back to your question, you can completely extract the code for judging the state, because there may be new states in the future. At that time, if a new state is added, there is no need to change the main process, just focus on the code for managing the state 
. 
But in this case, you still need if else to achieve this (you can't reduce its complexity).

Comment: @Dexygen I answered his question "This can be done with a bunch of IF conditions but is there a better way to do it?" My suggestion is to separate the state processing code from the main body, and I explained that in the end, these still have to be judged by if else. Maybe you can write some fancy algorithms, and then encapsulate them into a method, which can be judged by direct calling. 
But in the end that algorithm may need more if else

Comment: A bunch of IF/ELSE is definitely an option but the number of conditions that will be needed will be too many for any readable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite straightforward if you use [`ordinal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()):

```
public enum Status {
    CREATED, PROCESSED, UPDATED_STAGE1, UPDATED_STAGE2, UPDATED_STAGE3, UPDATED_STAGE4;

    public boolean isBefore(Status other) {
        return this.ordinal() < other.ordinal();
    }
}
```

Comment: ordinal is a good way. This works really well for my use case. Thanks for your help :)